# jQuery Corner Radius on Bottom Corners Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile and have a div, where I would like only the bottom 2 corners to have have that curved look.

From my reading i understand to this i should use:

`ui-corner-bl` and `ui-corner-br`

However this is not working. Oddly, `ui-corner-all` does work fine. Any ideas how to fix this?

The div looks like:

```
<div id="bottomSmall" class="ui-shadow ui-corner-bl">
    <img src="img/homepage/a.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After JQuery 1.2 they stopped supporting

`ui-corner-tl
ui-corner-tr
ui-corner-bl
ui-corner-br
ui-corner-top
ui-corner-bottom
ui-corner-right
ui-corner-left
ui-corner-none`

You will need to add your own CSS try:

```
    .ui-corner-tl {
    //Top left css
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: .6em;   
    border-top-left-radius: .6em;
    }
    .ui-corner-bottom {
    //Bottom left CSS
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: .6em;    
    border-bottom-left-radius: .6em;
    //Bottom right css
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: .6em;   
    border-bottom-right-radius: .6em;
    }
```